# Convert "duration" "Unit" to milliseconds

Tags: java, java-time

I want to have an API that looks like

```
public static long toMillis ( long duration, ChronoUnit unit ) {
   // magic duration to millis
}

toMillis( 5, ChronoUnit.SECONDS); // 5000
```

of course I'm not actually writing `toMillis` but that's essentially what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Could you use [`ChronoUnit#getDuration()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#getDuration--) and then convert that to milliseconds using [`Duration#toMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toMillis--)?

Comment: I assume this is related to the date/time API. If you're just looking for a unit conversion utility, you can use `TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(duration)`.

Comment: @shmosel oddly enough I found that API on here, and it would serve my purpose, but then I got frustrated with "why can't I figure out how to do this with java.time"

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use `Duration` for this:

```
Duration.of(5, ChronoUnit.SECONDS).toMillis()
```

Comment: I just found that `toXxx()` came from [java-9].

Comment: @JinKwon these methods are available in Java 8 as well: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toMillis--